# I want to hide rown in SQL Server but not want to remove it

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I want to hide the rows of null value but don't want remove it

Comment: how do you want to `hide` the rows ?

Comment: i WANT THE TOTAL NO OF ROWS INCLUDING NULL VALUE BUT DON'T SHOW IT

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to return them in your data? Could a row have a value of *`NULL`* for `Row_No`, but would have an actual value for `Company_address` for example?

Comment: @AshishMaurya Please don't shout. CAPS, gives that impression. Thanks. (It may well that you had CAPS lock accidentally on at the time, as you have a lowercase i instead, however, it's still not polite, and comments can be editted for 5 minutes).

Comment: then don't select those rows with NULL value. add the condition in your `WHERE` clause

Comment: actually i created a xtrareport and we want to fix no of rows in the receipt for that

Comment: So if you have 5 rows and one has NULL in a certain column, you want to show still `count = 5` but at the same time only show 4 rows in your report ?

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: `we want to fix no of rows in the receipt` . You should handle that in the select query not fixed the no of rows in the table

Comment: To see those Row_no also being null, I have a suspicion that the query that gives that result uses a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  And only the fields of the joined table are shown.  If you change it to an INNER JOIN then it will only return records where there's a match with the joined table. But maybe you're just looking for help about how to [count](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't play with the results in SQL Server, whatever you send as a `SELECT` is whatever you get as result set. If you want to tamper the results you will have to do so in your application or visual layer and not within SQL Server.

However, you can split your query into two parts: one to retrieve the total number of rows and another to actually get the filtered results. You will have to handle both results accordingly. Keep in mind that this is not a good approach, as you will have to "repeat" the query 2 times.

```
-- TotalRows
SELECT
    TotalRowsWithNulls = COUNT(1)
FROM
    YourTable AS T

-- Result set
SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable AS T
WHERE
    T.YourColumn IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wish not to see these NULL records while selecting the result, Just Add Filter in your Where Clause to Remove the NULL Records.

Maybe something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColName IS NOT NULL
```

Or you may create a View with all the Not NULL records and use that insated

Comment: This is Just a Sample. and you need to replace the Table name and column name with your table and Column. If still not working then please add your Code to the Question

Comment: @AshishMaurya How does this not work for you, can you explain better please

Comment: @GuidoG So if you have 5 rows and one has NULL in a certain column, you want to show still count = 5 but at the same time only show 4 rows in your report ? yes i want this

Comment: In such case, add an extra column in the Query to find the total count and display the count from that

Comment: @AshishMaurya then show us your query then we can help you with that